# Rendering CSS with HTML with Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I have the file main.html which is being returned unstyled even though I have style.css in /polls/static/polls/style.css

Here is main.html (cut down for simplicity)

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
  </head>
```

my settings.py has this for the static URL:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Yet it still returns it unstyled while the console gets returned 404 1671:

```
"GET /polls/static/polls/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1671
```

Here is my directory:
[image: Directory]

The fix is probably easy I'm just a newbie at Django

Thanks

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps check in developer tools if the css link is getting loaded?

Comment: I mean its obviously not getting loaded if I'm getting a 404 but the error I get is


`"GET /static/polls/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1671`

So the path is correct but its not loading it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `STATICFILES_DIRS` to your settings file. Like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'polls/static')]
```

Comment: This didn't change anything do i have to modify this somehow?
I edited settings.py to be:
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]`

But still same error